# Why Some(1).toString doesn't equal to "1", in scala?

Tags: scala

Thank you for any suggestions!

```
Some(1).toString.equals("1")        
False

Some(1).toString.getClass           
Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String
"1".getClass                        
Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String
```

Comment: It's "Some(1)". Why do you think it should be "1"?

Comment: **Some** is a "container" for some value and a type on its own. As mentioned by @TimDestan, the .toString is equal to "Some(1)". If you want to get the value **Some** holds, try .get. For `Some(1)` the result will be _1_, then you can turn it into a **String** and do the equals and get **True**

Comment: Also, what do you expect for `None.toString`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check what is inside an `Option`, use `contains`

```
Some(1).contains(1) // true
Some(2).contains(1) // false
None.contains(1) // false
```

If you want the `String` value of the element in the `Option`, use `fold` to specify the default value

```
Some(1).fold("")(_.toString) // "1"
None.fold("")(_.toString) // ""
```